# Can't run this Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey guys,
I clone a repo in Github: https://github.com/huacnlee/homeland/tree/

when I run the server, I got this error:

```
Agro:homeland Zhulin$ rails s
DEPRECATION WARNING: railtie_name is deprecated and has no effect. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Zhulin/Desktop/RailsApps/homeland/config/application.rb:9)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /Users/Zhulin/Desktop/RailsApps/homeland/config/config.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Zhulin/Desktop/RailsApps/homeland/config/application.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What should I do? And BTW where can I find simpler Rails code for learning Ruby and Rails,
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set up a `config.yml` file in the `config` folder. It looks like the repo includes a `config.yml.default` file that you can use as a template.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing your database configuration file `config/database.yml` for some reason. These are generated automatically by `rails new <appname>` so it is easy to get a replacement.

As for examples, a good reference book is always best. I like the [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) book, but there are many others.